# #if DEBUG preprocessor directive not working on Apple Store Xamarin App

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I just published an App in the Apple App Store and I'm having an issue with some parts of the app in which I use #if DEBUG directive.

I archived the app in "AppStore" mode and I don't understand why this is happening. Do you have any ideas?

Do I need to use a different directive?

BTW. In Android Play Store is working properly

Comment: you need to check your Compiler settings for the build configuration you used to submit to the app store and verify that  DEBUG is not set

Comment: #if DEBUG directive also doe not work for me. This is causing my test code to be published with production code :(

Answer (score 0):

You must check the Project Properties, regarding the compiler directives.

If you are using Visual Studio for Mac, check this:

[image]

If you are in Release Configuration, the DEBUG symbol must not be defined.

Comment: can't see the image.. could you share it again please?